# Delphi 2009 and Informix dbExpress with Windows 2003

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, informix, dbexpress

I have simple application that uses dbExpress to connect Informix database.
If I compile it with TurboDelphi it works on both WinXP and Win2003.

When I use new Deplhi 2009 my app works ok on WinXP but do not start on Win2003.
No MessageBox with error, only info in EventLog:

> Faulting application inf_dbexpress_test.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting
>   module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4062, fault address 0x0000bee7.

I think this is problem with dbExpress driver while my other app compiled with Delhi 2009 that uses
ODBC to connect Informix works on Win2003.

Anybody can test if Informix dbExpress drivers from Delphi 2009 works with Windows 2003?

---

Thanks for your help, but it do not work.

As for `$INFORMIXDIR`:
I reinstalled ClientSDK 3.5 and my `$INFORMIXDIR` is now:

> c:\informix

(was c:\Program Files ...).

I can connect to DB from my app that uses ODBC.
But dbExpress app can not start, even in WinXP compatibility mode.

---

I have reported it in Delphi Quality Central as [bug #67823:](http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=67823)

Answer (score 2):

Which turbo version do you have (the .net version or the Win32 version)? Do you have .net framework installed on 2003?

Comment: I have TD for Win32. I tried program on Win2003 with .NET framework installed (now I see this computers have .NET framework in versions 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1).

Comment: Can you try to install Deplhi 2009 on the 2003 machine, and try to debug your program there?

Comment: No. I used D2009 trial and it has expired :(

Answer (score 1):

Hm maybe a strange suggestion, but one of the big differences introduces in Delphi 2009 is Unicode. All strings are now Unicode strings. Could that possibly be an explanation for the problem?

Comment: This is very simple app: no code at all, just DB grid with simple query:

SELECT FIRST 1 DBINFO('version','full') FROM systables;

The same app works on XP. If there was something wrong with Unicode I think it wouldn't work on XP.

Comment: My second app compiled with D2009 works on Win2003, but instead of dbExpress it uses "hand" made ODBC.